# Realm doesn't contain user after register

Tags: swift, mongodb, realm

I'm developing a swift application using mongodb+realm. In my signup function, sometimes when the realm is returned it does not contain any users (but the created user is showing in the cluster). So I get a nil exception in hasSignedConsent. Am I missing something?

```
func signup() {
    app.emailPasswordAuth.registerUser(email: email!, password: password!, completion: { [weak self](error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self!.setLoading(false)
                guard error == nil else {
                    print("Signup failed: \(error!)")
                    self!.errorLabel.text = "Signup failed: \(error!.localizedDescription)"
                    return
                }
                print("Signup successful!")
                self!.errorLabel.text = "Signup successful! Signing in..."
                self!.login()
            }
        })
    }
```

```
func login(){
    setLoading(true)
    app.login(credentials: Credentials.emailPassword(email: email!, password: password!)) { result in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.setLoading(false)
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Login failed: \(error)")
                self.errorLabel.text = "Login failed: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                return
            case .success(let user):
                print("Login succeeded!")
                self.setLoading(true)
                var configuration = user.configuration(partitionValue: "user=\(user.id)")
                configuration.objectTypes = RealmManager.OBJECT_TYPES
                Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: configuration) { [weak self](result) in
                    self!.setLoading(false)
                    switch result {
                    case .failure(let error):
                        fatalError("Failed to open realm: \(error)")
                    case .success(let userRealm):
                        RealmManager.shared.setRealm(realm: userRealm, handler:{
                            if RealmManager.shared.hasSignedConsent(realmA: userRealm){
                                self?.scheduleReminders()
                                self?.goToViewController(storyboardID: "Main", viewcontrollerID: "home")
                            }
                            else{
                                self?.goToViewController(storyboardID: "Onboarding", viewcontrollerID: "consentVC")
                            }
                        })    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
func hasSignedConsent(realmA: Realm) -> Bool {
        let user = realmA.objects(User.self).first
        return user!.hasSignedConsent
    }
```

```
func setLoading(_ loading: Bool) {
        activityIndicator.isHidden = !loading
        if loading {
            activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            errorLabel.text = ""
        } else {
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
        emailTextField.isEnabled = !loading
        passwordTextField.isEnabled = !loading
        signupLoginButton.isEnabled = !loading
    }
```

here is my trigger that is fired when a new user is added:

[image]

and here is the createNewUserDocument function:

```
exports = async function createNewUserDocument({user}){
  const cluster = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas");
  const users = cluster.db("mseasedb").collection("User");
  return users.insertOne({
    _id: user.id,
    _partition: `user=${user.id}`,
    name: user.data.email,
    profilePicture: null,
    hasSignedConsent: false,
    gender: '',
    birthday: '',
    typeOfMS: '',
    diagnosisDate: '',
    treatmentBeginningDate: '',
    mascot: 'Drummer',
    canReadPartitions: [`user=${user.id}`],
    canWritePartitions: [`user=${user.id}`],
  });
};
```

Comment: Troubleshooting! First, take this `DispatchQueue.main.async` out as you are not doing anything in the UI. Second, please safely handle optionals. this `email!` will crash the app if it's nil. Safely unwrap it before using the var. Lastly, please isolate the issue; this code `case .success(let user):` should never fail. Add a `print(user.id)` right after that and step through the code, line by line awaiting for it to print nil. If it never prints nil, then you know that's not the issue and the issue is following that line.

Comment: @Jay Thanks! It's a bit difficult to troubleshoot it since the problem only happens sometimes (mostly in noon!). I feel that it is because when `Realm.asyncOpen` is called, the trigger is not fully executed (maybe due to some delays at that time of the day) and the user object is not inserted in the Realm. Do you think that's possible?

Comment: In the big picture, anything is possible, however, very unlikely. The nature of asynchronous functions  is that the code in the closure following the function will *never* run until it's valid or has an error. It just won't happen. So no, that isn't the issue. The results will only every have to states, `.failure` or `.success` and you can count on that. There are a number of other factors that could be affecting your code, for example, we don't know what `RealmManager` does.

Comment: RealmManager is a class that you can call Realm objects related functions through it using a static variable called `shared` (I was trying to use Singleton design pattern). Of course, the closure will run only after it's valid or has an error, but is the closure following `Realm.asyncOpen` check if the user is added to the realm or not? (since the user is inserted in the cluster after the trigger is fired). I guess not. Am I making sense?

Comment: `Realm.asyncOpen` requires a configuration and the only way to do that is to get the `user.configuration` when would mean the user object would have to be valid. In other words `let user = app.currentUser!` would crash/be nil if there wasn't a valid user object. I am still leaning toward it being a asynchronous issue as shown in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution! (Thanks to Andrew from [Mongodb community forums](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/realm-doesnt-contain-user-after-registeration/112471/3))

Basically, the problem is caused since triggers are asynchronous.
One of the solutions for my case was to split `user` object into 2 different objects (`user` and `profile`):

```
import RealmSwift

class Profile: Object {
    @objc dynamic var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId.generate()
    @objc dynamic var _partition : String = ""

    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var profilePicture: Data? = nil
    @objc dynamic var hasSignedConsent: Bool = false

    @objc dynamic var gender: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var birthday: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var typeOfMS: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var diagnosisDate: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var treatmentBeginningDate: String = ""

    @objc dynamic var mascot: String = "Drummer"

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "_id"
    }

    convenience init(email: String){
         self.init()
         self._partition = RealmManager.shared.getPartitionValue()
         self.name = email
     }

    func getPretestData()->(gender: String, birthday: String, typeOfMS: String, diagnosisDate: String, treatmentBeginningDate: String){
         return (gender: gender, birthday: birthday, typeOfMS: typeOfMS, diagnosisDate: diagnosisDate, treatmentBeginningDate: treatmentBeginningDate)
     }
 }
```

‌‌

```
import RealmSwift

class User: Object {
     @objc dynamic var _id: String = ""
     @objc dynamic var _partition: String = ""

     override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "_id"
     }
}
```

and after signing up I just create a profile in Realm.

Answer (score 0):

This is a total shot in the dark but I will take a guess and say at least part of the problem is being caused by embedding asynchronous calls within asynchronous calls.

Summarizing, the existing code does this

```
func signup() {
    app.emailPasswordAuth.registerUser { 
            DispatchQueue.main.async {            1
               app.login {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {    2
                         Realm.asyncOpen {        3
```

The only time you need DispatchQueue.main.async is if you want to update the UI - otherwise it's not needed as the networking is all happening on background threads.

This pattern will probably fix the issue (this is a summary, not copy/paste)

```
app.emailPasswordAuth.registerUser {
    app.login {
       switch result {
       case .failure(let error):
           print("Login failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
       case .success(let user):
           print("Successfully logged in as user \(user)")
           // Remember to dispatch to main if you are doing anything on the 
           //  UI thread. Like this to add the id to a textField
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.someTextField.stringValue = user.id
           }
           Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: configuration) { (result) in
              switch result {
              case .failure(let error):
                 print("Failed to open realm: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                 // Handle error...
              case .success(let realm):
                // Realm opened - do realm stuff
```

If you notice, there's only one DispatchQueue and that's to update the UI - no other networking code was embedded in those calls

Comment: Thanks for the response! Actually, I do have some UI updates which I didn't include in the question to make it easier to read. I will edit it.

Comment: I couldn't fix the problem by tweaking `DispatchQueue.main.async`... However, I recently noticed that whenever this problem happens the log shows: "Client bootstrap completed in ... Received 1 download(s) containing 1 changeset(s) ...." which should be actually 2 changesets. does it help?